# spring boot app crashing on cloud foundry java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, manifest, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy an app on PCF at pivotal.io trial account. My springboot app works fine locally using java -jar, but when I push my app to PCF it crashes. I was able to get the app up and running by changing some dependencies in my gradle but that caused one of my other lib(fabric-connector) to not work. 
I've posted my logs from PCF, gradle.build and manifest below. Thank you.
Please help.

```
  applications:
  - name: ****app
    buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git
    memory: 1G
    instances: 1
    path: ./build/libs/*****-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

2018-04-06T12:44:29.862-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 17:44:29.851 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/classes/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.106.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.106.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.106.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.106.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.59.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/classmate-1.3.4.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/client_certificate_mapper-1.6.0_RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-compress-1.16.1.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/evo-inflector-1.2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/fabric-connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/fabric-connector-autoconfigure-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/fabric-sdk-java-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/google-auth-library-credentials-0.3.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/google-auth-library-oauth2-http-0.3.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-all-0.13.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-auth-0.13.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-context-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-core-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-netty-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-okhttp-0.13.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-protobuf-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-protobuf-lite-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-protobuf-nano-0.13.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/grpc-stub-1.10.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/gson-2.8.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/guava-19.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/httpclient-4.5.5.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/httpcore-4.4.9.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/httpmime-4.5.5.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/ion-java-1.0.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.10.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.json-1.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.1.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jmespath-java-1.11.106.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jna-platform-4.2.2.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.9.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.11.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-all-4.1.22.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-http2-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-codec-socks-4.1.17.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.17.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.7.Final-osx-x86_64.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-2.0.7.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/netty-transport-4.1.21.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/objenesis-2.6.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/okhttp-2.5.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/okio-1.6.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/opencensus-api-0.11.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics-0.11.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/proto-google-common-protos-1.0.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/protobuf-java-util-3.5.1.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/protobuf-javanano-3.0.0-alpha-5.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/shim-client-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.17.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-core-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.10.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-hateoas-0.23.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/spring_auto_reconfiguration-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.27.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.27.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/]
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 17:44:29.867 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.properties'
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at aig.pilot.moneymovement.MoneymovementApplication.main(MoneymovementApplication.java:10)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:71)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:366)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:302)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:173)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:226)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:737)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyType(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:497)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.resolvePropertyName(RelaxedDataBinder.java:420)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.getActualPropertyName(RelaxedDataBinder.java:384)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.initializePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:273)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.normalizePath(RelaxedDataBinder.java:259)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperty(RelaxedDataBinder.java:240)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:155)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:548)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:541)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.handleProfileProperties(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:533)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.doLoadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:494)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:473)
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 25 common frames omitted
2018-04-06T12:44:29.929-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Exit status 1
2018-04-06T12:44:29.935-05:00 [CELL/SSHD/0] [OUT] Exit status 0
2018-04-06T12:44:30.045-05:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell f89ef217-9f6c-48b6-b8a2-214da3e26a21 stopping instance 4ce7028d-fb06-4a4b-7a55-92e7
2018-04-06T12:44:30.046-05:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell f89ef217-9f6c-48b6-b8a2-214da3e26a21 destroying container for instance 4ce7028d-fb06-4a4b-7a55-92e7
2018-04-06T12:44:30.053-05:00 [API/1] [OUT] Process has crashed with type: "web"
2018-04-06T12:44:30.062-05:00 [API/1] [OUT] App instance exited with guid 6dfeba9e-9d31-43ff-af26-5cebba412de6 payload: {"instance"=>"4ce7028d-fb06-4a4b-7a55-92e7", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"APP/PROC/WEB: Exited with status 1", "crash_count"=>6, "crash_timestamp"=>1523036670023060604, "version"=>"63416894-2ce7-4b18-8877-1f1d4640fe77"}
2018-04-06T12:44:30.602-05:00 [CELL/0] [OUT] Cell f89ef217-9f6c-48b6-b8a2-214da3e26a21 successfully destroyed container for instance 4ce7028d-fb06-4a4b-7a55-92e7
```

This is my gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

group = '*****'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
    gradleVersion = "4.2.1";
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

configurations{
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.22.Final'

    compile('io.netty:netty-common:4.1.17.Final')
    compile('io.grpc:grpc-core:1.10.0')
    compile('io.grpc:grpc-netty:1.10.0')
    compile('io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.10.0')
    compile('com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1')

    compile('ibm.cic.br.bc:fabric-connector-autoconfigure:1.0-SNAPSHOT')
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")
    extraLibs group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '4.2.2'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

jar{
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also have checked the jar and see the application.properties that it say's its not there:
Huys-MBP-2:moneymovement huytran$ unzip -l build/libs/moneymovement-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep application.properties
       76  04-06-2018 12:04   BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties

Comment: First thing, don't do this `buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git` in your application.yml.  You don't want to point to the master branch because it can change out from under you.  Who knows, it could even be broken at the moment and cause problems.  Point to the buildpack provided by the platform, like `java_buildpack` or point to a release like `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#v4.9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevent error looks like this one:

```
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2018-04-06T12:44:29.869-05:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60)
```

And this post seems to indicate it's due to a mix of Spring Boot 1.5, which I can see in your gradle file, and Spring 5.0, which I don't directly see.  So, check your dependency tree and see if you can figure out what is pulling in Spring 5.0.

[Nullpointer exception thrown when running Sprint Boot with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190639/nullpointer-exception-thrown-when-running-sprint-boot-with-spring-mvc)